# Передача в метод System.out.print() массива

Tags: java, массивы

Когда я передаю в к̶о̶н̶с̶т̶р̶у̶к̶т̶о̶р̶ метод `System.out.print()` ссылку на массив, например:

```
int[] expected = new int[]{1, 2};
System.out.print(expected);
```

Что выводится в консоль?

Comment: Почему бы вам не попробовать и посмотреть на результат?

Comment: Попробывал  [I@74a14482, что это?

Comment: У меня немного другой массив там, не тот что здесь

Comment: Это адрес вашего массива

Comment: @ДенисФедичкин, это не адрес!

Comment: Вот то то и оно, сомнения у меня тоже по поводу того, что это адрес

Comment: А кто сказал вам, что это конструктор? Это метод. [Как работает](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17121338/4549213)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В Java все массивы (да, даже те, элементы которого являются примитивными типами) наследуются из `Object`. Соответственно, у всех массивов есть метод `hashCode()`.

`@` - разделитель. До него находится информация об объекте. После него результат метода `hashCode()` для этого объекта.

`[` означает, что передаваемое является массивом. Сразу после него идёт информация о том, какой тип у элементов этого массива.

```
+-----------------------+------------+
| Z                     | boolean    |
+-----------------------+------------+
| B                     | byte       |
+-----------------------+------------+
| C                     | char       |
+-----------------------+------------+
| S                     | short      |
+-----------------------+------------+
| I                     | int        |
+-----------------------+------------+
| J                     | long       |
+-----------------------+------------+
| F                     | float      |
+-----------------------+------------+
| D                     | double     |
+-----------------------+------------+
| L полное-имя-класса ; | имя-класса |
+-----------------------+------------+
```

[Официальная документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures)

Answer (score 3):

В консоль выведется результат метода 'toString()' класса Object:

```
public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

Т.е. примерно: `[I@74a14482`